# Get html checkbox list checked values to a hidden field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, yii

How to get the checked checkboxes id in to a hidden variable?

I am getting this error.

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

var test = $('input[name=\'data-grid_c0[]\').val();
```

**data-grid_c0** is the name of the checkbox array.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="data-grid_c0[]" id="data-grid_c0_1" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="data-grid_c0[]" id="data-grid_c0_2" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="data-grid_c0[]" id="data-grid_c0_3" value="1">
```

Below is the jquery code i have written.

```
$('#deleteall-button').click(function () {
   var atLeastOneIsChecked = $('input[name=\"data-grid_c0[]\"]:checked').length > 0;
   var test = $('input[name=\'data-grid_c0[]\').val();

   alert(test);
   if (!atLeastOneIsChecked)
   {
     alert('Please select atleast one record to delete');
   }
   else if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the records?'))
   {
     document.getElementById('search-form').action = 'index.php?r=device/bulkDelete';
     document.getElementById('search-form').submit();
   }
});
```

I want the value of **data-grid_c0** to be assigned to **selectedDevices** hidden field.

```
<form action="hotelSearch/hotelSearch" method="post"><input id="selectedDevices" type="hidden" value="" name="selectedDevices" /><a id="deleteall-button" class="btn btn-primary">Bulk Delete</a></form>
```

So with php i will be able to handle it as following and delete,

```
//check-boxes
if (isset($_POST['selectedDevices'])) { //data-grid_c0
    $del_camps = $_POST['selectedDevices']; //data-grid_c0
    $model_camp = new Device;
    foreach ($del_camps as $_camp_id) {
        $model_camp->deleteByPk($_camp_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just post the checkboxes themselves theyll get posted as a csv anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a closing `]` and a closing `'`

`var test = $('input[name=\'data-grid_c0[]\').val();`

Should become

`var test = $('input[name=\'data-grid_c0[]\']').val();`

As others have pointed out, you don't necessarily have to escape those inner quotes.

`var test = $('input[name="data-grid_c0[]"]').val();`

Answer (score 2):

You have incorrect selector to target checked check box and also you are not getting the id correctly. Use:

```
$('input[name="data-grid_c0[]"]:checked').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 2):

***Escaping*** is not necessarily needed here, you can use **meta-characters** as a string inside of the selectors.

```
var atLeastOneIsChecked = $('input[name="data-grid_c0[]"]:checked').length > 0;
var test = $('input[name="data-grid_c0[]"]').val();
```

And using `"` inside of a `'` wrapped segment would be considered as a string, Don't confuse in that.